# Haskell function to convert Int to alpha numerotation

Tags: haskell, number-formatting, numeric

I'm trying to write a Haskell function to convert an integer number into a string with a alpha numerotation.

By alpha numerotation, I mean the numerotation matching to this conversion :

```
1 -> A
2 -> B
3 -> C
..
25 -> Y
26 -> Z
27 -> AA
28 -> AB
29 -> AC
..
```

I found this [function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5550/converting-to-roman-numerals) to convert a decimal number to a Roman number and tryed to modify it to do what I want. But I didn' managed to have the correct result. The problem is that in alpha numerotation, the "A" have not the same "weight" when used as a unit or a multiple (it can be worth 1 or 0).

**Do you know how to obtain the correct conversion ?**

Comment: You are converting to base 26, where the digits are the letters A-Z.

Comment: What, no zero?  Positives only?

Comment: Yes this function is to reproduce the numerotation used in Office calc columns, LaTeX/HTML chapter numbering (`counter(subsection,upper-alpha)`)

Comment: This is easy to get wrong, since it is very similar to converting to base 26, but with a subtle difference on the first letter. In base 26, the first digit ranges from `1` to `25`, while all the others range from `0` to `25`. Instead, in the enumeration above all the letters range from `A` to `Z`.

Comment: @chi You're right, I didn't realize this subtlety. I would have gotten it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty easy with modular arithmetic. We'll write a function that returns the letters in reverse order; we can fix it up at the top-level afterwards. The basic idea is to repeatedly divide by 26. So:

```
rawCellName :: Int -> String
rawCellName x | x <= 0 = []
rawCellName x = toEnum (fromEnum 'A' + r) : rawCellName q where
    (q, r) = (x-1) `quotRem` 26
```

Then at the top level we just fix up the API oddity:

```
cellName :: Int -> String
cellName = reverse . rawCellName
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
> map cellName [1..5]
["A","B","C","D","E"]
> map cellName [25..30]
["Y","Z","AA","AB","AC","AD"]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can here first convert the number to a sequence of numbers by each time dividing it by 26, and calculating the modulo:

```
import Data.List(unfoldr)

toColumnName :: Int -> String
toColumnName = reverse . fmap (toEnum . (64+)) . unfoldr f
    where f 0 = Nothing
          f n = Just ((mod (n-1) 26)+1, div (n-1) 26)
```

or shorter:

```
import Data.List(unfoldr)
import Data.Tuple(swap)

toColumnName :: Int -> String
toColumnName = reverse . fmap (toEnum . (65+)) . unfoldr f
    where f 0 = Nothing
          f n = Just (swap (divMod (n-1) 26))
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.List> map toColumnName [1..100]
["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","AA","AB","AC","AD","AE","AF","AG","AH","AI","AJ","AK","AL","AM","AN","AO","AP","AQ","AR","AS","AT","AU","AV","AW","AX","AY","AZ","BA","BB","BC","BD","BE","BF","BG","BH","BI","BJ","BK","BL","BM","BN","BO","BP","BQ","BR","BS","BT","BU","BV","BW","BX","BY","BZ","CA","CB","CC","CD","CE","CF","CG","CH","CI","CJ","CK","CL","CM","CN","CO","CP","CQ","CR","CS","CT","CU","CV"]
```